# How to share android 4g internet connection by LAN?

Tags: networking, wi-fi, usb, lan

I have IP camera and printer that is accessible via internet. They can be connected via wifi or LAN (both have this rj45 port). I wonder if it's possible to share my 4g android connection through LAN?

I have tried using the following setup

> OTG (microusb to usb) - usb to LAN port - LAN cable

But it doesnt seem to work ("USB tethering" option remain disabled)

Any suggestion?

Comment: USB tethering usually makes the phone simulate an Ethernet adapter via USB to a connected PC, so I don't think it can work via OTG and a connected Ethernet USB adapter.

Comment: *OTG (microusb to usb) - usb to LAN port - LAN cable* No, this can't possibly work unless for some weird reason your Android supports an USB Ethernet adapter (the wrongly called "usb to LAN port" here) and if it does then "USB tethering" has nothing to do with it. This feature is the phone's internal Ethernet over USB and you tied to add ANOTHER Ethernet device that, assuming the best case scenario (device recognized) it can only be used for the phone to get internet, never to share it.

Comment: And for what purpose you want to do this? It's unlikely that your mobile ISP allows access to the devices from outside your LAN anyway due to CG-NAT and other mobile-only quirks. If however you only need the devices to access the internet, as opposed to be accessed *from*, then just enable WiFi tethering and connect them with WiFi.

Comment: @Robert i used to share my 4g connection smoothly to my laptop when working in rural areas with USB tethering. So i am doing this under assumption if sharing internet to PC is possible, then why wouldnt in another LAN supported peripherals. I always prefer wired over wifi for security and performance reason

Comment: @ChanganAuto so are you suggesting there is no way to share internet from android to LAN supported devices?

Comment: No, I never suggested that, merely hinted that 1. your idea seems weird and (and you still haven't told us what's your goal) 2. even if doable - it isn't - it probably won't work if the purpose is accessing the aforementioned devices from outside your LAN. If it's for the devices to access the internet (e.g. obtain firmware updates) sure it works but then WHY not use WiFi? So, again, what's the purpose of connecting the devices (so far you only mentioned peripherals) to the internet? Are there more devices and some must be connected via Ethernet? If so you need a ROUTER with Ethernet ports  ..

Comment: (...) Most domestic routers have multi-purpose USB ports that support internet access via USB modems -and- tethered phones (note: ISP provided ones might not if they blocked that feature in the firmware). No need for the USB Ethernet adapter. Your misunderstanding probably stems from bridged connections in desktop computers for which such USB adapter is at the end of the day an Ethernet port like any other. But you CAN'T do this in a phone. Phones, by default, only do Internet to "USB emulated Ethernet" or WiFi (AP), not the other way around. Your setup seems nonsensical, unless you clarify.

Comment: To be clear: There's nothing technically speaking that prevents a smartphone from 1. supporting an USB Ethernet and 2. configuring a bridged network connection. The former is a matter of drivers and the latter software. It's just that such usage is so unusual that people don't even think about it. Don't reinvent the wheel by making it square, Mythbusters already did it and concluded that square wheels are rubbish and an health hazard.

Comment: appreciate your brief answer. however the goal is rather simple - connect the device (i.e IP camera) to internet provided by 4g phone. as for why not using wifi, i already mentioned that i ALWAYS prefer wired over wireless. so here in SE asking for possibility. Wifi works fine if you ask me. but again, just wondering if there's any workaround how to make it possible share 4g internet to IP-device with ethernet port

Comment: There is and I already commented about it: Use a ROUTER with Ethernet ports and at least one USB port where you'll then connect the phone or any dedicated USB 4G/5G modem. End of story.

Comment: I see. So the setup would be: 4g phone, data cable (microusb to usb), router (with usb port), ethernet cable from router to device- correct? Also since i need to share phone internet to router (and not the other way around) i would need to enable "USB tethering" option? really thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, exactly as described.